# Looping through table of values to see if they are present in a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am not very familiar with loops in SQL, but need to do the following.

I have a list of 250 column names and need to check if they are present in a number of large tables.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProcTextSearch]       
(   
    @procName AS VARCHAR(MAX),
    @strFind AS VARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;         
    BEGIN
        SELECT  @strFind ColumnName
            ,OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) SP_Name
              
        FROM   sys.procedures
        WHERE   OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) = @procName
    AND OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) LIKE '%'+@strFind+'%'
    END 
END
GO
```

I have a proc that takes the procName and a string to see if this is present in a given procedure that populates a table.

Is there a way I can change this so it will loop through all 250 column names and return those that are present?

Trying to ascertain what columns from a source system we might already be using by searching procedures that populate tables. I need to check the text within the procedure as some of the source system columns may have been renamed. So with a set of 250 column names, is there a nice way of doing this?

Comment: Don't use loops, they are dreadful for performance. If you want to find a whole list of potential values then using a table valued parameter would be much better. Of course with that leading wildcard in your where predicate performance is going to be a bit rough anyway. That begs the question, why do you need a stored procedure to find what other stored procedure may reference a particular value?

Comment: @SeanLange It does not need to be a SP, but how can I search a proc to see if ~250 potential values are in there?

Comment: Still use a table type, @Linus81 . That the SQL isn't in a procedure is irrelevant to the solution; the procedure just allows for a parametrised call to your solution.

Comment: You would use a table of values that you want to find and then use a join. This has a smell to it though that you are concerned about that many possible values in the text of a procedure. What I mean is I have used this type of thing a couple times for analysis but nothing that is used all the time.

Comment: With SQL try to revise your thinking to "sets" for example rather than "list of 250 column names" it might be rephrased "set of 250 column names" since really what a stored procedure does is define a "set" of data to return or query.  Looping through a "set" filtered by another "set" thus can be "select from a set" with values from "another set of data"

Comment: Feels like an X-Y problem here to me at the moment.  What is the REAL problem you are attempting to solve?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Trying to ascertain what columns from a source system we might already be using by searching procedures that populate tables. I need to check the text within the proc as some of the source system columns may have been renamed. So with a set of 250 column names, is there a nice way of doing this?

Comment: This feels like a task normally done in your source control/code project for all your stored procedures.  You do have source control correct?

Answer (score 0):

you can combine queries

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'

SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='your_table_name'
```

in addition, for stored procs you can check sp text

```
EXEC sp_helptext 'HumanResources.dEmployee';  
sp_helptext @objname = N'AdventureWorks2022.Sales.SalesOrderHeader', @columnname = TotalDue ;  
GO
```

as another option to see all sp's with data. check this query

```
SELECT * 
  FROM [master].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
 WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE' 
   AND LEFT(ROUTINE_NAME, 3) NOT IN ('sp_', 'xp_', 'ms_')
```

Comment: Perhaps revise to focus on "stored procedures" vs "table" sets given the OP question as it is now.

Comment: thank you @MarkSchultheiss - i updated answer to include additional approach